# OpenGL ES 2.0: How to Implement Simultaneous Multi-Color gl_FragColor?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

I have an OpenGL ES Android app and I want to find a way to make multiple sections of the screen glow in different colors simultaneously. The app itself divides the screen into 6 columns and that column illuminates with a unique color when the user touches it.

The problem i'm having is that when the user multi-touches the screen the columns all glow the same color instead of their unique colors. The cause is my renderer logic overwriting the gl_FragColor everytime a touch is detected in a column. Since the columns all use the same shader, the columns all glow as the most recently set color during multi-touch situations.

How can I achieve making each column glow it's unique color when touched when the user is touching more than one column at a time? Since gl_FragColor is an auto-generated variable i'm not sure how to add more gl_FragColors, assuming that would help solve the issue.

**fragment_shader**

```
precision mediump float;         // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a
// precision in the fragment shader.
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;              // The input texture.

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;  // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
varying vec3 v_Position;            // Interpolated position for this fragment.
varying vec4 v_Color;            // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the triangle per fragment.
varying vec3 v_Normal;           // Interpolated normal for this fragment.

uniform vec4 ColumnGlowColor;          // color of the Column

uniform vec2 eColumnGlowPosition;   // where the Column is
uniform float eColumnGlowSizeScale; // the size to scale the glow
uniform vec2 aColumnGlowPosition;
uniform float aColumnGlowSizeScale;
uniform vec2 dColumnGlowPosition;
uniform float dColumnGlowSizeScale;
uniform vec2 gColumnGlowPosition;
uniform float gColumnGlowSizeScale;
uniform vec2 bColumnGlowPosition;
uniform float bColumnGlowSizeScale;
uniform vec2 eeColumnGlowPosition;
uniform float eeColumnGlowSizeScale;

float generateGlow( vec2 pixelPosition, float ColumnGlowScale, vec2 touchPosition){
if(stringGlowScale == 0.0) {
    return 0.0;
}
else if (touchPosition.y > pixelPosition.y){
    highp float distance = length(touchPosition-pixelPosition);  // the horizontal distance from the current pixel and the light source
    highp float threshold = .5*stringGlowScale;                             //defines the effect width
    highp float effectScale = sin((max(threshold-distance, .0))/threshold); // using sin function smooth the effect
    return effectScale;
}
else{
    highp float distance = abs(touchPosition.x-pixelPosition.x);  // the horizontal distance from the current pixel and the light source
    highp float threshold = .5*stringGlowScale;                             //defines the effect width
    highp float effectScale = sin((max(threshold-distance, .0))/threshold); // using sin function smooth the effect
    return effectScale;
}
}

// The entry point for our fragment shader.
void main(){
    highp float effectScale = 0.0;
    effectScale += generateGlow(v_Position.xy, eColumnGlowSizeScale, eColumnGlowPosition);
    effectScale += generateGlow(v_Position.xy, aColumnGlowSizeScale, aColumnGlowPosition);
    effectScale += generateGlow(v_Position.xy, dColumnGlowSizeScale, dColumnGlowPosition);
    effectScale += generateGlow(v_Position.xy, gColumnGlowSizeScale, gColumnGlowPosition);
    effectScale += generateGlow(v_Position.xy, bColumnGlowSizeScale, bColumnGlowPosition);
    effectScale += generateGlow(v_Position.xy, eeColumnGlowSizeScale, eeColumnGlowPosition);

    lowp vec4 fromTexture = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);

    gl_FragColor = fromTexture + ColumnGlowColor*effectScale; 
}
```

**Renderer**

```
 public class OpenGL_GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
     ...

     private void setUniforms(int programHandle){
            ...
            mGlowColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "stringGlowColor");           //glow color
            mStringID = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "stringNum");
            mGlowPosHandles[0] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "eStringGlowPosition");      //glow effect position on neck
            mGlowScaleHandles[0] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "eStringGlowSizeScale");   //glow effect strength
            mGlowPosHandles[1] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "aStringGlowPosition");
            mGlowScaleHandles[1] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "aStringGlowSizeScale");
            mGlowPosHandles[2] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "dStringGlowPosition");
            mGlowScaleHandles[2] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "dStringGlowSizeScale");
            mGlowPosHandles[3] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "gStringGlowPosition");
            mGlowScaleHandles[3] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "gStringGlowSizeScale");
            mGlowPosHandles[4] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "bStringGlowPosition");
            mGlowScaleHandles[4] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "bStringGlowSizeScale");
            mGlowPosHandles[5] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "eeStringGlowPosition");
            mGlowScaleHandles[5] = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "eeStringGlowSizeScale");

            //************************Column Glow code*******************************
            //if user's touching the screen, make nearest string glow
            for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++) {
                if (stringGlowEffects[i] != null) {
                    float top = orthoTop + (orthoBottom-orthoTop)*stringGlowEffects[i].y + scroller.getCurrentValue();
                    GLES20.glUniform2f(mGlowPosHandles[i], stringGlowEffects[i].x, top);
                    float glowEffectScale = 1.0f + (50.0f) / 300.0f;
                    GLES20.glUniform1f(mGlowScaleHandles[i], glowEffectScale);      //TODO: allow multiple colors simultaneously
                    switch (i){
                        case 0:
                            GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle,.0f, .0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle,.0f, 1.0f, .0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle,1.0f, .0f, .0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle,.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle,1.0f, 1.0f, .0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle,1.0f, .0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    GLES20.glUniform1f(mGlowScaleHandles[i], 0.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: can't you discard multi touch events?

Comment: @UtsavShrestha I could but I dont want to. Multi-touch is part of the app's normal behavior and the shader needs to be able to handle that.

Comment: In that case I'll upvote the question, hopefully someone with more experience with shaders will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the easiest way to solve your problem is to set the color per grid square, instead of having a single uniform for the color. You have already done this for the position and sizes of the columns, you could easily extend this to record the color of each column.

In your shader, you'd change `ColumnGlowColor` to an array (easier than having 6 separate variables, as with your position and scale variables):

```
uniform vec4 ColumnGlowColor[6];          // color of the Column
```

How to actually apply this to the output color is hard to say, since you don't show that code about how the glow is actually calculated. It seems reasonable to assume that the `generateGlow` function returns the intensity of the glow at the input location. Instead of returning an intensity, you would have it return an float4, which is the color (in RGB components), and intensity in alpha. You would then change your final line of your pixel shader to just:

```
gl_FragColor = fromTexture + sumOfReturnsFromGenerateGlow;
```

When you get the location of the uniform you may need to add the array operator, to bind it correctly (some drivers are permissive about this, others, not). Your original name was `stringGlowColor`, but it should match the uniform name:

```
mGlowColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "ColumnGlowColor[]");
```

When you are setting the `mGlowColorHandle` value, you would set each array entry, by setting the adding the index to the uniform. Eg, for the first column set would change to:

```
GLES20.glUniform4f(mGlowColorHandle+i,.0f, .0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

NOTE: You can output multiple colors from your shader, if you use the [EXT_draw_buffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_draw_buffers.txt) GLES extension. However, this is not what you want to do, as I'm assuming you don't have multiple framebuffers.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how I would change my shader to implement this color-per-square functionality (i'm new to OpenGL ES). Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post to include the generateGlow() method logic. You're correct that I return an intensity value from this method. How could I determine which color values to return within this method? An if-else block that picks a color based on x-axis touch position? I'm not sure how to determine the width of the screen from this scope so I don't know how I can easily test which of the 6 screen columns touchPosition.x resides in.